# How to get range of the values of a key in dictionary?

Tags: python

e.g.

```
my_dict = {key1:['a', 1,'b', 2], key2:[9, 'q', 'x']}
```

For key1 there are 4 values for key2 there are 3 values

What i need to do is loop through each value for each key.

I tried:

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    for items in my_dict[key].values():
        #do something for each value tied to the key looped in the first for loop
```

Comment: And you thought that including a comment would do what, exactly? What are `mask_node` and `mask`? What *"something"*? Your example doesn't make sense, and I see no attempt at any real implementation; please give a [mcve].

Comment: I don't even understand what you mean by "get range of the values of a key."

Comment: What are `mask_node` and `mask`?

Comment: @Goyo it was a mistake.. i meant my_dict instead mask_node, and key instead of mask ( i fixed my post though) - However Simon already gave an answer, thanks thgough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understood your question, but something simple as

```
for elem, vals in my_dict.iteritems():
    for val in vals:
        # do something with val, e.g.
        print val
```

should do the job.